# AngularJS Вывод ответа функции?

Tags: angularjs

Доброго дня. В Angular'e новичок. Не могу вывести ответ от функции:

```
   $scope.record = function(rid) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "http://site.com/device/record/",
                            data: {'rid' : rid
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                rec = JSON.parse(data);
                                console.log('ОТВЕТ: ', rec[0].filename);
                                return (rec[0].filename);
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
                                console.log(jqXHR);
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Вызываю и передаю параметр:

```
<p ng-bind="record('3271831')"></p>
```

В консоли ответ отображается корректно, но не отображается на экране. В чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функция `$scope.record` ничего не возвращает, поэтому и не меняется. Присваивайте результат в переменную $scope, а не возвращайте его. И используйте $[http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) или [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) вместо `$.ajax` иначе у вас работать ничего не будет, и вам придется писать очередной вопрос.

Comment: Так вместо return -> $scope.record = rec[0].filename; ?

Comment: Да, типо того. Только прочитайте мой ответ до конца, т.к. это с .ajax работать не будет.

Comment: Ок. А вывести просто ng-repeat'ом?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов зависит от данных